# Magento 2 checkout page redirection

Tags: checkout, mini-cart, magento-2.1.7, redirect-url

I want to redirect the 'proceed to checkout' action in mini cart to a custom page. I can't set the new link in mini cart button. 
http://i.prntscr.com/ZGS7nessQsSMlbjZHSFj0Q.png

Comment: another page page menas?

Comment: To a custom page

Comment: Check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205802/how-to-change-process-to-checkout-url-of-minicart-in-magento-2-2-1/205808#205808

Answer (score 3):

You add a custom link to the 'proceed to checkout button' in `minicart.js.`

This can be found under `magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view`

In that file you will see `'url':{ 'checkout'`

Comment: shall we redirect to cart page?