# How to change process to checkout url of minicart in Magento 2.2.1

Tags: mini-cart, magento-2.2.1

I want to change **"Process to checkout"** url of minicart with custom theme.

I override content.html in my custom theme but I don't know how we change url of button.

```
<div class="actions" if="getCartParam('possible_onepage_checkout')">
    <div class="primary">
        <button
                id="top-cart-btn-checkout"
                type="button"
                class="action primary checkout"
                data-action="close"
                data-bind="
                    attr: {
                        title: $t('Go to Checkout')
                    },
                    click: closeMinicart()
                "
                translate="'Go to Checkout'"
        />
        <div data-bind="html: getCartParam('extra_actions')"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to this file : vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js

then check this code :

```
  'url': {
                'checkout': window.checkout.customerLoginUrl,
                'update': window.checkout.updateItemQtyUrl,
                'remove': window.checkout.removeItemUrl,
                'loginUrl': window.checkout.customerLoginUrl,
                'isRedirectRequired': window.checkout.isRedirectRequired
            },
```

Change the 'checkout' for URL changing.

for example :

```
  'url': {
                'checkout': 'google.com',
                'update': window.checkout.updateItemQtyUrl,
                'remove': window.checkout.removeItemUrl,
                'loginUrl': window.checkout.customerLoginUrl,
                'isRedirectRequired': window.checkout.isRedirectRequired
            },
```

**Note:** First add this file in our custom theme on this location : http://example.com/app/design/frontend/Nameplace/Themename/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/minicart.js

Comment: Thanks for answer. But __shoppingCartUrl__ is used in view cart but I want to change __Process To Checkout__ url

Comment: Check mine updated answer

Comment: @DSingh, how to link proceed to checkout link to cart page?

Comment: @jafarpinjar this worked for me: `'checkout': window.checkout.shoppingCartUrl`

Comment: @DSingh can i add custom url in this?

Comment: @Fenashah Yes, you can add the custom URL as well.

Comment: @DSingh okay! Thank you :)

Comment: how to overwrite this file in custom module ?